# FlatList that renders components that contain FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am having trouble getting an 'nested' FlatList to scroll. I have disabled the parent FlatList scrolling by passing scrollEnabled = {false} but that had no effect. I think the parent FlatList is intercepting the scroll events and I have not been able to find anything online that could be a possible solution.

```js
export const createStyles = () => {
  return {

    baseStyles: {
      height: 70,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      width: 200,
      paddingHorizontal: 5,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: StyleConst.colors.grey.lighter3,
      borderRadius: 3,
    },
  };
};

export const createItemStyle = (index, len) => {
  console.log(index, len);

  if (index !== len - 1) {
    return {
      borderBottomColor: StyleConst.colors.grey.lighter2,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      width: 150,
    }
  }
}
export class Dropdown extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    data: arrayOf(object),
    handleChange: func,
    valueExtractor: func.isRequired,
  }
  renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.handleChange(this.props.valueExtractor(item))}>
        <View key = {item.id}>
          <Text>
            {item.item.value}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const styles = createStyles();
    return (
      <View style={styles.baseStyles}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          onScrollBeginDrag={() => console.log("start")}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```